# Agregar un botón para cargar Excel en Django admin

Tags: python, django

Tengo creada una vista y una URL para cargar un archivo Excel, esto funciona muy bien, ahora necesito agregar un botón con la URL de esta vista.

Me gustaría agregar este botón al costado del botón `Add article` que se muestra en la siguiente imagen (la imagen es referencial):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La URL sería http://0.0.0.0:8000/admin/cargos/cargo/importar-cargos/

Comment: Amigo, si en dado caso necesitas un sistema para importar y exportar en distintos formatos de tabla, puedes usar django-import-export, este agrega los respectivos botones que te llevan a una vista con opciones para exportar: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar un nuevo boton se debe crear un nuevo template en `admin/nombre_app/nombre_modelo/change_list.html` con el siguiente contenido:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <li>
        <a href="importar-excel/" class="grp-add-link grp-state-focus">
Importar excel</a>
    </li>
{% endblock %}
```